# php-mcrypt dependency issues when installing on CentOS (latest server release)

Tags: php, centos, mcrypt

When executing **yum install php-mcrypt*** I get the following error.

```
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.28-4.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: php-common = 5.3.28-4.w5
           Installed: php-common-5.4.30-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php-common = 5.4.30-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.2.17-1.1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common = 5.2.17-1.1.w5
           Available: php-common-5.3.27-2.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common = 5.3.27-2.w5
           Available: php-common-5.3.28-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common = 5.3.28-1.w5
           Available: php-common-5.3.28-2.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common = 5.3.28-2.w5
           Available: php-common-5.3.28-3.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common = 5.3.28-3.w5
           Available: php-common-5.3.28-4.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common = 5.3.28-4.w5
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-common = 5.4.16-21.el7
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.28-4.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: libltdl.so.3()(64bit)
```

Do I need to downgrade my php-common or is there a better alternative?

Please be detailed in your response as this is my first experience setting up LAMP on a CentOS machine.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by upgrading to PHP 5.5 and then installing any required extensions by using the following command format.

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 reinstall php-mcrypt
```

It seems that none of my installation attempts wanted to play nicely with PHP 5.4.30.